# S3 static website with multiple pages (like SPA)

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to have put up a simple website, which I want to host in AWS S3. The site has multiple pages, but just like what's common, it should be some fixed header / footer, only the center content of the page changes whenever the user clicks any of the links Home / About / Contact Us ... etc (just like how a Single-Page Application behaves). Is there a way to do this as a static website hosted in S3? Or do I need to repeat the header / footer for every link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to duplicate the header and footer for each page - use a javascript framework like angular or jquery etc,  and you can centralize common elements for each page without depending on a server-side logic to accomplish this.